# Auto-crop pdf from command line

Tags: pdf, crop

I need to automatically crop a pdf file (remove white margins). So far, I tried two tools which aren't perfect:

1. pdfcrop

Issue: it doesn't crop some pdfs.

2. pdf-crop-margins

Issue: sometimes it crops too much (fine details).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,.. I render very long single page PDF's with `wkhtmltopdf` like such

```
wkhtmltopdf \
--disable-javascript \
--print-media-type \
--zoom 2 \
--page-width 750px \
--page-height 100000px \
https://www.foobar.com \
foobar.pdf;
```

Than I need to trim off all the whitespace on the bottom
I tried `Briss` https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/briss#default, but that did not work for me.

So I tried `pdfcropmargins` that did not work for you and Bingo!

On MacOs 11.6 I need to access the command like so:

```
/Users/<usernamehere>/Library/Python/3.8/bin/pdfcropmargins -p 0 foobar.pdf;
```

That will crop with a file write out named *foobar_cropped.pdf*